# finding $a,b,c,d$ of $\frac{x^2 +ax + b}{x^2 +cx +d}$ from its plot

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, quadratics, fractions

We Want to find $a,b,c,d$ of $\frac{x^2 +ax + b}{x^2 +cx +d}$ from its plot. If they can be found accurately, found the exact number. If they can be an interval, find that interval. (note that the extremum of plot is not at an accurately known point, we just know that its $x$ is between $(0,1)$ and $y$ is negative)

From the plot, I can find that the numerator must be $(x+1)(x-2) = x^2 - x -2$ so I get $a=-1 ,b=-2$. I can Also found that the denominator must not have real roots so $c^2 - 4d <0$ but I cannot find $c,d$ Note that it is known that $c , d$ has accurate values or intervals like $c=-4,d>10$ (just for example). So I don't want parametric answers like $-2\sqrt d < c < 2 \sqrt d$.

[image]

Comment: If you know the numerator, it should be straightforward to find three points on the denominator and then solve for the quadratic.

Comment: From the $y$-intercept, I guess that $b/d=-2/3$, so $d=3$.  You should be able to find $c$ now.

Comment: In fact, the graph seems to be symmetric about $x=1/2$, and since the numerator is symmetric about $x=1/2$, the denominator should also be.  That is, $c=-1$ must hold.

Comment: @Batominovski I think your second answer seems logical. because the actual graph was printed on a small paper and the only thing that was obvious from the graph was x intercept $(-1,2)$. so finding symmetry seems better than approximation from the graph. I can find $d>1/4$ from $c =-1$.   Please submit your answer so I can make it best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This answer is subject to possible errors due to inaccurate readings of the graph.

The $y$-intercept of the graph ***seems*** to be at $y=-\frac23$, whence $\frac{b}{d}=-\frac23$ should be the case.  As $b=-2$, we conclude $d=3$.

The graph ***occurs*** to be symmetric about the line $x=\frac12$.  Therefore, the function is symmetric about the same axis.  Since the numerator $x^2+ax+b=x^2-x-2=\left(x-\frac12\right)^2-\frac{9}{4}$ is symmetric about this axis, the denominator must also be symmetric about $x=\frac12$ too.  That is, $x^2+cx+d=\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+k$ for some constant $k$.  Hence, $c=-1$.

The plot below shows the plot for $y=\frac{x^2-x-2}{x^2-x+3}$.  This looks almost identical to the OP's graph.

[image: This Graph Looks Quite Like the Graph in the Problem Statement]